# ?wtx=Y showing up on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

This isn't a typical question but it is web related and pertaining to a clients website. I've done some research on it and wanted to check and see if anyone on here is had issues like this.

```
#1: /Fanuc-servo-motor-repair/?wtx=Y
#3: /?wtx=Y
#26: /yaskawa/?wtx=Y
```

As you can see, these urls all end with ?wtx=Y. Does anyone know what could be causing this? It's kind of hard to explain to a client when I can't figure out where it's coming from myself. Would it be pertaining to an account like Google AdWords or AdCenter(Bing/Yahoo)?

Answer (score 0):

Are they hosted on Webvanta? -  `wtx` is their taxonomy param.

See: http://support.webvanta.com/support_article/615767

(Currently not considered on-topic for stack overflow, webmasters is probably the best place for this - Google Analytics questions are not really well-placed in either place - there's a certain level of programming skill required to get moderately complicated GA installations working correctly, but the interpretation of the reports isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow - cross-Stack Exchange tags would probably be the right answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please note although whilst this answer is not addressing where the parameters are coming from it might be of use.

In the profile setup admin panel you can set Analytics to ignore certain parameters. This would stop this 'wtx' parameter appearing in your reporting.

See: [Exclude URL Query Parameters](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1010249)